# Photoshop CC always using Legacy transform

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

Okay; this is going to sound weird I guess; but I was one of those people who actually liked the new way Photoshop uses transform; I like that I don't need to hold SHIFT to proportional transform.

But for some reason; I'm stuck in legacy mode; I have the option in the preferences turned off but still I have to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>. In every layer type (pixel; vector; text).

I'm using Photoshop CC 21.0.3 (latest) on macOS.

How do I get back to the new way of transforming?

Comment: No help eh? I am in the same boat.

Answer (score -1):

See this, fixed it for me, hopefully it will work for you: https://www.reddit.com/r/photoshop/comments/h0rn5c/use_legacy_free_transform_check_box_broken/

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. While this may answer he question, link only answers are generally discouraged here because links tend to rot over time. Can you please edit your answer, and mention what steps need to be taken to fix the problem. Thanks.